# > operator as arithmetic operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is it considered "bad practice" to use the greater then and less than operators as arithmetic operators? If so, why?

I have an "image" struct and I would like to use these operators to return threshold applied images.

Comment: depends if you want anyone else to read your code or not. Consider using `<<` and `>>` instead?

Comment: How are those any better @Matt?

Comment: They are arithmetic operators whereas `<` `>` are relational

Comment: Superb answer. Thanks

Comment: Plus, `<<` and `>>` are already overloaded, so the user will be more ready to accept that they might do something besides bit shifts or stream handling.

Comment: "already overloaded"?

Comment: "Often overloaded", maybe, e.g. `cout << "blah"`

Comment: Also the meaning of `<<` and `>>` in C only makes sense for numeric types, so nobody reading your code will think they actually perform shifts. With `<` and `>` the situation is different and most programmers would assume they're really comparison operators.

Comment: I can't delete this post but it is getting a lot of negative votes. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overload them to whatever you feel like, it's all good as long as it makes sense in the context you are using them.

That being said, I can't imagine a situation where overloading < > == and != to do something completely different would make sense. Those operators are pretty standard - every major language is using them as comparison operators and in my opinion, most programmers will expect them to do just that.

It's a convention - like green button to start, red button to stop. But if you think it makes sense for your app, then sure, go ahead.